# Where does input validation belong in an MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, language-agnostic, model, controller

I have a MVC application that receives an input from a form.
This is a login form so the only validation that is necessary is to check whether the input is non-empty.
Right now before I pass it to the model I validate it in the controller.
Is this a best practice or not? Does it belong to the model?

Comment: Simple answer: [put it where it’s needed.](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/02/15/validation-in-a-ddd-world.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's an official best practice limiting validation to any single part of the MVC pattern.  For example, your view can (and should) do some up-front validation using Javascript.  Your controller should also offer the same types of validation, as well as more business-logic related validation.  The model can also offer forms of validation, i.e., setters not allowing null values.

There's an interesting discussion of this [at joelonsoftware](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.354410.16).

Comment: I assume there's some Javascript somewhere in the app?  Unless this is an old-fashioned Web 1.0-style web app or framework.

Comment: There is but I don't touch/code/handle it unless I really really really want to :)
In this framework the View only creates and initializes the widgets and attaches them to the root widget. It can have validation functions in it though. So the view is the place for validating if the data non-empty but the model is for verifying that the inputted username and password are correct?

Comment: Also should the view call model functions? That couples them and it loses the whole point. So here's what the controller is doing right now: validating for non-empty values and passes it to the model. Should I make the view call the controller that will call the model authentication method and then return an answer to the controller that will return an answer in the view? That sounds like a major overhead.

Answer (score 8):

I have been thinking about this for a LONG time and after trying putting validation in both controllers and models.... finally I have come to the conclusion that for many of my applications... validation belongs in the model and not in the controller. Why? Because the same model could in the future be used by various other controller calls or APIs... and then I would have to repeat the validation process over and over again. That would violate DRY and lead to many errors. Plus philosophically its the model which interacts with the database ( or other persistent storage ) and thus is sort of a 'last call for alcohol' place to do this anyway.

So I do my get/post translation in the controller and then send raw data to the model for validation and processing. Of course I am often doing php/mysql web applications and if you are doing other things results may vary. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

**Validation must be in the Model**

Only the model knows the "details" of the business. only the model knows which data is acceptable and which data is not. the controller just knows how to "use" the model.

for example: let's say we need the functionality of registering new users to our system.

The Model:

```
 public function registerUser(User $user){
    //pseudo code
       //primitive validation
       if(!isInt($user->age)){
           //log the invalid input error
           return "age"; 
       }
       if(!isString($user->name)){
           //log the invalid input error
           return "name";
       }
       //business logic validation

        //our buisnees only accept grown peoples
        if($user->age < 18){
            //log the error
            return "age";
        }
        //our buisness accepts only users with good physique
        if($user->weight > 100){
            //log the error
            return "weight";
        }
        //ervery thing is ok ? then insert the user
        //data base query (insert into user (,,,) valeues (?,?,?,?))
        return true;
}
```

Now the controller/s job is to "use" the model `registerUser()` function without the knowledge of how the model is going to do the validation, or even what is considered "valid" or not!

the Controller:

```
$user = new User();
$user->age = isset($_POST['age']) ?  $_POST['age'] : null;
$user->name = isset($_POST['name']) ?  $_POST['name'] : null;
$user->age = isset($_POST['weight']) ?  $_POST['weight'] : null;
$result = $theModel->registerUser($user);// <- the controller uses the model
if($result === true){
//build the view(page/template) with success message and die
}
$msg = "";
//use the return value from the function or you can check the error logs
switch ($result){
    case"age" :
        $msg = "Sorry, you must be over 18";
        break;
    case "name":
        $msg = "name field is not correct";
        break;
    case "weight":
        $msg = "Sorry, you must have a good physique";
        break;
}
//build the view(page/template) with error messages and die
```

The class user

```
class User { 
    public $age;
    public $name;
    public $weight;
}
```

having an architecture like that will "free" the controllers completely from the details of the business logic -which is a good thing-.

Suppose we want to make another form of user registration somewhere else in the website (and we will have another controller allocated for it). now the other controller will use the same method of the model `registerUser()`.

But if we distributed the validation logic between the controller and the model they will not be separated -which is bad and against MVC- meaning that every time you need to make new view and controller to register new user you must use the same old controller AND the model together. Moreover if the business logic is changed (we now accept teenagers in our sports club) you are going only to change the code in the model `registerUser()` function. the controllers code is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Its business logic, so no, it doesn't belong in the model.

Comment: The answer below claims otherwise. Please elaborate and explain why do you think so.

Comment: I would likely go the route darren outlined below.  In which case, it would go in your service layer.
Basically, think of it like this; is not allowing an empty string a constraint placed on you by the model?  And its not a UI concern.  So it must be a business concern; a user cannot log in with an empty username.

Comment: Uh. If your doing MVC properly business logic BELONGS in the model, not the view or the controller. Application logic belongs in the controller, and the view is the view.

Arguably validation is not business logic but application logic, but thats kind of splitting hairs.

Answer (score 0):

Within the controller you have the ModelState property to which you can add validation errors to.

See [this example on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is structured like:

- Model-View-Controller
- Service
- Persistence
- Model

The user input would come to your controller, and you would use services in the service layer to validate it.

Comment: More layers? What's the service layer? There is no database so there is no persistence per se, all the data is taken from another process and all the data is changed either from the UI or the process.

Answer (score -3):

```
Business Logic  -> Controller
Data Validation -> Model
```

Comment: The above answer says it's business logic so it doesn't belong to the model. You are saying that it does right?
I'm confused. Please elaborate and explain why do you think so.

Comment: I disagree. I would say: Business Logic -> Domain; User interface logic -> Controller; Validation -> Domain + UI (optional)

Comment: @the_drow: I'm saying that business logic **doesn't** belong in the Model, it belongs in the Controller.

Comment: **@Martinho:** @unknown and @Kaleb seem to share my opinion.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Yes but what I said is that 'unknown (google)'s answer says otherwise. Please explain why?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: What's Domain? UI is View?

Comment: Let me clarify: By Domain I mean what is known as the Domain Model, Domain Layer or sometimes Business Logic Layer (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html).
UI is the User Interface. MVC is a user interface architecture (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).
What I said above is that business logic does not belong in the user interface but in the domain layer. Validation should be in the domain layer, but it can also be used in other layers, like the UI (probably in the Controller or the View in Js) to give fast feedback to the user.