# What is the best way to notify the user that their input is incorrect when setting a class property in a Java console app?

Tags: java, console

Let's assume that the user is creating a "User" class which represents their profile:

```java
public class User {
   private int age;

   public User(int age) {
      if (age < 150)
         this.age = age;
      else
         System.out.println("Incorrect age, try again");
   }
}
```

Since we don't want `age` to be greater than 150, if the user inputs 170, we should tell them that they made a mistake.

However, printing in the class doesn't seem clean, and printing in the constructor even less so. What would be the best way to achieve this ? Similarly, how would you check the input when modifying `age` via a setter ?

Comment: You might want to throw exception, then catch and handle it(notify). But there is no best way, depends on what you want to happen in the case of invalid input.

Comment: If the input is invalid, it would be best if the user was notified, then invited to try again

Comment: @anatoliy121 In that case, you might want to keep prompting the user for an age until you get a valid one and only create the `User` object after that.

Comment: I'd combine the 2 approaches: check the age before creating the user but also check in the setter and throw an exception if validation fails. You want to catch invalid input early on but at the same time don't want to trust any code external to the class to maintain those constraints.

Comment: So it would be best to check the values before creating the objects, but when you'd change the value it would be best to handle that check in the setters?

Answer (score 1):

Throw an appropriate `Exception` to indicate the problem.

```java
public User(int age) {
  if (age < 150)
     this.age = age;
  else
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age >= 150");
}
```

Comment: But that would stop the program, right?

Comment: @anatoliy121 You can catch the Exception and handle it.

Comment: I suppose that the same thing could be applied to setters. However, isn't it dull to check the value of every constructor parameter that way?

Comment: @anatoliy121 Then you can check all the input before creating the `User` object.

Comment: In an MVC pattern, would the input be checked in the view?

Comment: @anatoliy121 See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068627/where-does-input-validation-belong-in-an-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you can check for the age before you create the object.

Alternatively you could make the constructor private and use a method like this to create the object:

```
public static User createUser(int age) {
    if (age >= 150) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too old");
    }
    return new User(age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A design alternative instead of throwing exception might be: if they pick a value over the max, just set it to the max.

As an aside it's generally a good idea to return a value to the caller to signal what action was taken by the method.  If you update the value, return the updated value.  If you didn't update the value, return the existing value. That way the caller and decide what to do if the value was or was not updated.

You could also return a boolean value to signal if the age was updated or not.

Another idea to follow is the "principle of least surprise" which you can think of as: what would the caller expect to happen if the value is out of range...  as an example outsider, I would think that the age doesn't get set and it tells me what the acceptable ranges are so I can pick again, or better yet it only lets me pick acceptable values so I don't have to go back and forth.